# how to show and hide 2 tab-pane bootstrap with angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tab-panels and links but I dont know how to show one or the other clicking in the links.

```
          <!-- Tabs navs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill mb-3" id="ex1" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="ex2-tab-1" (click)="showPictures();" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="ex2-tabs-1" aria-selected="true">Pictures</a
                >
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <a
                    class="nav-link"
                    id="ex2-tab-2"
                    (click)="showMap();"
                    data-mdb-toggle="tab"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="ex2-tabs-2"
                    aria-selected="false"
                    >google Maps</a
                >
                </li>
            
            </ul>
            <!-- Tabs navs -->
            
            <!-- Tabs content -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div
                class="tab-pane fade show active"
                id="div1"
                *ngIf="div1"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="ex2-tab-1"
                >
               
    </div>
    <div
      class="tab-pane fade"
      *ngIf="div2"
      role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="ex2-tab-2"
      id="div2"
    >
      google maps no se muestra
      {{room.mapgoogle}}
    </div>
 
  </div>



  div1:boolean=true;
  div2:boolean=true;

  showPictures(){
      this.div1=true;
      this.div2=false;
      console.log(this.div1);

      return this.div1;
 

  }

  showMap(){
      this.div2=true;
      this.div1=false;
      console.log(this.div2);
      return this.div2;

  }
```

how to activate each panel with angular I tried with *ngIf but doesnt work. also when I click in link "pictures" the component get an error and redirect to home.component.html.

Answer (score 1):

It is directed to home.component.html (the main page) is because of the href="#" inside the anchor tag.

Try to change your anchor tag to div instead.

```
<div (click)="yourFunction()"><button> Picture </button><div>
```

Please let me know if this is working. Thank you.